# IE 7 with backgorund image and position with js hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-sprites

I am using the js for before hack in IE 7.It displays the background image for the class.But now I want to position the image.Because it is sprite.I dont know why its not working .below is my code.

JS hack.http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/

```
.magento{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin:0; padding:0;
        padding-left: 20px;

    }

    .magento li:before 
    {
         display: inline-block;
         position: absolute;
         margin: 9px 0 0 -20px;
         min-height: 9px;  
         background: url(images/bulletsprite.png) no-repeat -116px 0px;
         *before: url(images/bulletsprite.png);
         *background-position-x: -116px;
         *background-position-y:0px;
         content:"";
        // vertical-align: middle;
         width: 9px; 
         height: 9px;
         float:left;
    }
```

HTML code

```
<ul class="magento">
        <li>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla sapien, varius id dignissim sit amet, luctus elementum nulla. Mauris hendrerit tincidunt nunc condimentum accumsan. Donec semper hendrerit ligula non blandit. Nullam tellus lacus, dictum quis sodales id, consectetur posuere nunc. Maecenas massa nibh, sagittis quis hendrerit ornare, interdum sit amet tellus. Proin lectus neque, posuere at interdum vitae, eleifend id dui. Mauris eget eros magna, sed gravida quam.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla sapien, varius id dignissim sit amet, luctus elementum nulla. Mauris hendrerit tincidunt nunc condimentum accumsan. Donec semper hendrerit ligula non blandit. Nullam tellus lacus, dictum quis sodales id, consectetur posuere nunc. Maecenas massa nibh, sagittis quis hendrerit ornare, interdum sit amet tellus. Proin lectus neque, posuere at interdum vitae, eleifend id dui. Mauris eget eros magna, sed gravida quam. 
        </li>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla sapien, varius id dignissim sit amet, luctus elementum nulla. Mauris hendrerit tincidunt nunc condimentum accumsan. Donec semper hendrerit ligula non blandit. Nullam tellus lacus, dictum quis sodales id, consectetur posuere nunc. Maecenas massa nibh, sagittis quis hendrerit ornare, interdum sit amet tellus. Proin lectus neque, posuere at interdum vitae, eleifend id dui. Mauris eget eros magna, sed gravida quam.  
        </li>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla sapien, varius id dignissim sit amet, luctus elementum nulla. Mauris hendrerit tincidunt nunc condimentum accumsan. Donec semper hendrerit ligula non blandit. Nullam tellus lacus, dictum quis sodales id, consectetur posuere nunc. Maecenas massa nibh, sagittis quis hendrerit ornare, interdum sit amet tellus. Proin lectus neque, posuere at interdum vitae, eleifend id dui. Mauris eget eros magna, sed gravida quam.  
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Also its in IE7 standard mode only . why the background-position is not working. The same code works fine in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 didn't come out until October of 2006. The plugin you're using says that it was last updated on February 6th, 2006. I'm guessing it was never made to work with anything other than IE 5 and IE 6.